# How to find algorithm to calculate 2 bytes of checksum from CAN message KIA auto

Tags: datetime

Can anyone tell me the algorithm to calculate checksum (B0 B1) of the KIA AUTO CAN Mesage, how it is calculated from other byte?

[algorithm to calculate 2 bytes of checksum from CAN mesage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tPsx.jpg)

ID DLC CRC Data Bytes
B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 B10 B11 B12 B13 B14 B15
03A0 16 F4 7B 2D 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 B9 93 2E 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 9D 3B 2F 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 8D 61 30 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 A9 C9 31 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 E4 21 32 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 C0 89 33 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 5F E1 34 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 7B 49 35 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 36 A1 36 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 12 9 37 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 08 70 38 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 2C D8 39 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 61 30 3A 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03A0 16 45 98 3B 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00